# How to edit an archive in linux with a ssh file?

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, vagrant, text-editor

I'm using vagrant here and i want to edit some archives to configure apache mod_rewrite, but how i will do this in ssh?

```
# I just need to Edit the archive /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and 
# put the 'AllowOverride none' to 'AllowOverride All'
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. It sounds like you want to automate altering a file on a remote system. What have you tried so far? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your question

--
I'm using vagrant here and i want to edit some archives to configure apache mod_rewrite, but how i will do this in ssh?

## I just need to Edit the archive /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and

### # put the 'AllowOverride none' to 'AllowOverride All'

putting AllowOverride to none to All will enable for you to use .htaccess 
in directories that need mod_rewrite rules. SSH Terminal will 
open up an editor that will allow you edit the file.

Comment: Yeah, but vagrant will load a script that will make, basically, all that configuration, but i need edit this archive in this script.

This script will do all for me